# How can I get an absolute path to a theme?

Tags: 7, theming, uri

Is there a Drupal function that returns the absolute theme path? Or is there a canonical / base practice way of doing this correctly returning the theme path?

What I've found so far is this:

```
<?php
// @file template.php
$template_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . drupal_get_path('theme', 'foo');
```

I'm looking to require_once the template path in a template.php file like so:

```
<?php
$template_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . drupal_get_path('theme', 'coo');
// ...
// Check file exists etc
require_once $template_path;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`base_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) function would return the base bath of the Drupal installation

> Returns the base URL path of the Drupal installation. At the very
>   least, this will always default to /.

and [`path_to_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) will return the path to the current theme.

> Return the path to the current themed element.
>
> It can point to the active theme or the module handling a themed
>   implementation. For example, when invoked within the scope of a
>   theming call it will depend on where the theming function is handled.
>   If implemented from a module, it will point to the module. If
>   implemented from the active theme, it will point to the active theme.
>   When called outside the scope of a theming call, it will always point
>   to the active theme.

Comment: Beware using the `path_to_theme()`, in case of subtheme your path will be broken, because it will point to your subtheme instead of the main theme! And subtheme doesn't need to have the same files and structure as the main theme. So if you need to create your theme's a subtheme, don't use `path_to_theme()`.

Answer (score 2):

Mohammed Shameem's answer is correct, but if you're really looking for the correct way (the Drupal way) to render a custom template, do not use `include()` or `require_once()`. Instead, use the Drupal theme system. Changing the output of something that already has a template is easy, see [Overriding themable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628) to learn how to override a template. If there is no template yet, you would have to learn about [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/hook_theme), registering your own templates, and render arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module: [System stream wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper)

It provides wrappers(examples from module's site) :

- module://file/icons/text-plain.png
- theme://bartik/screenshot.png
- theme://default/screenshot.png
- profile://minimal/minimal.info
- profile://current/standard.info (profile://current expands to the
  active profile for the site)
- library://ckeditor/images/spacer.gif (works only if the Libraries
  module is enabled)