# Why won't my images appear inside buttons?

Tags: media

In the page displayed, there is a row of buttons that each say "Submit Query."

[image]

The HTML for one of these buttons is:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="../images/OneLine30px.png" CLASS="select-button" ID="OneLine">`
```

I've also tried slightly modifying the paths to these images. This HTML is in a `.tpl.php` file which is inside the `templates` directory. The `images` directory is a sibling of the `templates` directory.

1. Why is Drupal displaying "Submit Query" instead of the image?
2. How can I get Drupal to display the images?

Comment: By the way, that "Submit Query" text is a browser default for image-type inputs that don't have a valid "src" image. Drupal isn't doing that. Fixing the "src" attribute should be enough.

Comment: If the image is in the theme folder have a look at [How can I get an absolute path to a theme?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58329/how-can-i-get-an-absolute-path-to-a-theme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly advise to use CSS for this, it's much more easier to apply and you won't hit path related issues.

Comment: Agreed. It is best practice which allows for the themers to have greater freedom. Sometimes site builders are doing everything and best practices fall by the wayside, but what happens when the site is handed over to someone else where the division between coders/builders/themers are in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your "src" attribute is a relative path, but on the web, it won't be relative to the "templates" directory where your tpl.php file lives. It will be relative to the current URL path, instead.

Try using absolute paths starting with "/", and see if that gets the images showing.

Comment: Absolute paths are not working... Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you including the "/drupal-7.15/" in the absolute URL?

Comment: yes, here is the tag I am using: `<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="/var/www/html/drupal-7.15/sites/all/modules/lewis/images/OneLine30px.png">`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus that looks like a server path, not a site path - most Drupal installs would begin at the parent of sites, not 4 generations up from that